# Tibbles reject lubridate's duration and period objects

Tags: r, lubridate, tibble

**Code that works: `duration` and `period` objects**

The following code successfully produces a `duration` object and a `period` object respectively.

```
> lubridate::as.duration(1)
[1] "1s"

> lubridate::seconds(1)
[1] "1S"
```

**Code that doesn't work: `duration` and `period` objects in `tibble`s**

However, when I try to create `tibble`s using a `duration` or a `period` object, I get uninformative error messages.

```
> tibble::tibble(y = lubridate::as.duration(1))
Error: Incompatible duration classes (Duration, numeric). Please coerce with `as.duration`.

> tibble::tibble(y = lubridate::seconds(1))
Error in x < 0 : cannot compare Period to Duration:
coerce with 'as.numeric' first.
```

**Code that works: `duration` and `period` objects in `data.frame`s**

Replacing `tibble::tibble` with `base::data.frame` works.

```
> data.frame(y = lubridate::as.duration(1))
   y
1 1s

> data.frame(y = lubridate::seconds(1))
   y
1 1S
```

**Code that doesn't work - coercing these `data.frame`s to `tibbles`**

Using `tibble::as_tibble` to coerce these `data.frame`s to `tibbles` yields the same error as before.

```
> tibble::as_tibble(data.frame(y = lubridate::as.duration(1)))
Error: Incompatible duration classes (Duration, numeric). Please coerce with `as.duration`.

> tibble::as_tibble(data.frame(y = lubridate::seconds(1)))
Error in x < 0 : cannot compare Period to Duration:
coerce with 'as.numeric' first.
```

**Possible explanation**

Hadley mentions something in this Github issue - https://github.com/tidyverse/tibble/issues/326 - about S4 columns, which include `as.duration` and `as.period`. Nothing is specifically mentioned about incompatibility.

Digging in the source code, I find the following chain of dependencies that give the same error message: `as_tibble.data.frame --> list_to_tibble --> new_tibble`

In `tibble:::list_to_tibble`, the only argument passed to `tibble::new_tibble` is `x`. Consequently, `subclass` is assigned the default value of `NULL`, and the penultimate line of `tibble::new_tibble` becomes

```
class(x) <- c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")
```

The objects have a structure, but trying to call them directly yields an error.

```
> x <- data.frame(y = lubridate::as.duration(1))
> class(x) <- c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")
> str(x)
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   1 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ x:Formal class 'Duration' [package "lubridate"] with 1 slot
  .. ..@ .Data: num 1
> x
Error: Incompatible duration classes (Duration, numeric). Please coerce with `as.duration`.

> x <- data.frame(y = lubridate::seconds(1))
> class(x) <- c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")
> str(x)
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   1 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ y:Formal class 'Period' [package "lubridate"] with 6 slots
  .. ..@ .Data : num 1
  .. ..@ year  : num 0
  .. ..@ month : num 0
  .. ..@ day   : num 0
  .. ..@ hour  : num 0
  .. ..@ minute: num 0
> x 
Error in x < 0 : cannot compare Period to Duration:
coerce with 'as.numeric' first.
```

Consequently, it appears that assigning the class of the `data.frame` `x` the vector `c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")` causes `R` to try to coerce `x` in a way that throws an error.

Furthermore, given that `tibble::tibble` also calls `as_tibble` (albeit not on a `data.frame`), I would hazard a guess that my issues with `tibble::tibble` have the same cause.

**Package versions**

- Tibble: 1.4.1
- Lubridate: 1.7.1
- R: 3.4.3

Comment: Another R user encountered the same problem and opened an issue on Github: https://github.com/tidyverse/tibble/issues/358. Leaving the question unanswered for now, as Hadley hasn't responded to the issue yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue is now resolved as of pillar v.1.2.1 (https://github.com/r-lib/pillar/issues/88).